# Seach a text on a list of childs Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumber-java, xpath-1.0

I have a problem because I do not know how to check or search if a text (String) is contained in a child element of a list.
I have the following:

```
<div class="father_class">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="Elements">Profile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="Elements">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to search on "father_class" if there is any "child" class which has the text Profile (as an String input).
I have try with the following code (Cucumber on Java for Selenium), but it is not possible to include Profile as a String:

```
@FindBy (className="father_class")
private WebElementFacade Father
Father.containsElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='child']/div[contains(text(), 'Profile')]"));
```

But here the problem is that this 'Profile' is not entered as a String which is what I want:

```
@FindBy (className="father_class")
private WebElementFacade Father
String var = "Profile"
Father.containsElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='child']/div[contains(text(), var)]"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try this `By.xpath("//div[@class='child']/div[contains(text(), "+var+")]")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close enough. To pass a variable e.g. `var` within the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
@FindBy (className="father_class")
private WebElementFacade Father
String var = "Profile"
Father.containsElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='child']/div[contains(., '" +var+ "')]"));
```